# Ordering levels of a factor in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to plot the following data by a given rank and to specify this rank in `geom_plot`? Or should I order the factor before. I mean, I want to plot the ids in the following order B, A, C, where B is dark blue and C is light blue.

```
tim.seq <- seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00", origin="1960-01-01", tz="GMT"),
               as.POSIXlt("2013-07-8 00:00:00", origin="1960-01-01", tz="GMT"),
               by="1 hour")
id <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], length(tim.seq), T, prob=c(0.4,0.8,0.2)))
rank <- factor(id, levels=levels(id), label=c(2,3,1))
data <- data.frame(time=tim.seq, id=id, rank=rank)

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=..count.., alpha=id))
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(fill="darkblue", binwidth=60*60*24, position="identity")
p1 <- p1 + scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(1, 0.2))
p1
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevel your `id` factor:

```
library(ggplot2)
tim.seq<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),
             as.POSIXlt("2013-07-8 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),by="1 hour")
id<-factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3],length(tim.seq),T,prob=c(0.4,0.8,0.2)))

rank<-factor(id,levels=levels(id),label=c(2,3,1))
data<-data.frame(time=tim.seq,id=id,rank=rank)
# Relevel factor id
data$id <- relevel(data$id, "B")

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=..count.., alpha=id))
p1<-p1+ geom_bar(fill="darkblue",binwidth=60*60*24,position = "identity")
# Changed your direction of alpha range
p1<-p1+ scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.2, 1))
p1
```

[image: barplot]

To get the colour gradient the other way around, you need to change your scale from `alpha` to something like `colour`, as alpha-blending won't display lighter colours on top of darker ones, but blends them, making the plot unreadable (try for yourself with `scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(1, 0.2))`). This I'll leave up to you, however.

Comment: Many thx, but `data$id <- relevel(data$id, "B")` looks a little kludgely if you want to reorder it before I suggest `reorder(data[,"id"],data[,"rank"],length)` is more general way.